# how to add new property to react useContext state

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state-management, use-context

I have a little problem, I'm learning reactjs. I'm trying to add a property to an object in the cart array called quantity; when similar item with same id is equal to the iterator, to add a property quantity and increase it's value. I'm learning both react and javascript I'm coming from a python background so...
Here is my code.

```
 const addToCart = (item) => {
    if (cart.length){
        for (let iter of cart){
            if (iter.id===item.id){
                item.quantity += 1 // this is 'NaN' if quantity wasn't declared.
                setCart([...cart, item])
            }else{
                setCart([...cart, item])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code does... Nothing!

Comment: Your code seems to add `item` to the array even if the id is found. Is this intentional?

Comment: No, I'm still learning react and js what I wanted to do was to create a property in item object called quantity and update its value if similar if the iterator ID and item ID matched.

Comment: When I manually push item the cart after updating quantity value. It also does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to increment the quantity if the item exist in the cart, otherwise add it to the cart ? if so try the following:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

...

const addToCart = (item) => {
    // declare the quantity property if it doesn't exist
    item.quantity = item.quantity || 1;
    // get the index from the cart
    const i = cart.findIndex(obj => obj.id === item.id);
    // if the item exists increment the quantity
    if(i > -1) {
      const newCart = [...cart];
      newCart[i].quantity = item.quantity + 1; 
      setCart(newCart)
    } else {
      // the item doesn't exist so add it to the cart
      setCart([...cart, item]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't throw error, but doesn't work also.

Comment: Like I said, I don't really know the working of react and js but, after changing `if(cart.length){}` to `if(cart){}` it started working.

Comment: It's hard to find the issue without a minimal reproducible example, but I think you can get rid of this test if you're sure the `cart` is always an array

Comment: Yes, It's always an array of objects.

Comment: The code inside `if(cart.length)` will not execute if `cart` is empty, check my updated code